# Equality of two sets in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I was recently reviewing local university's math entrance exam. Majority of questions are really trivial, however I can not find a reason for why the following equality should hold:

$$\{n \mid n \text{ is divisible by } 2,3 \text{ and } 4\} = \{k \mid k \text{ is a multiple of } 24\}.$$

$12$ is divisible by $2$, $3$ and $4$, however it is not multiple of $24$. Then, why should the two sets be equal?

Comment: you are correct.

Comment: Although your title says otherwise, this question has nothing to do with linear algebra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, they are not equal.

Your institution presumably made the careless mistake of thinking $\text{lcm}(2,3,4) = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4$, but since $2,3,4$ are not coprime this is not true. $12$ would be an example of that (and begets infinitely many by the rule $12+24k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$).